# Automatically prevent extra line spacing because of math

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing

The boxes and glue system seems to be both the strength and weakness of TeX. One of the major problems I often have to deal with is uneven distances between lines as in the example below.

[image]

Inserting some `\smash` commands around the math proves that this extra line spacing is not at all necessary; there is plenty of room for the math on lines of standard height:

[image]

Currently, inserting `\smash` commands manually is the only acceptable solution I have found to this problem, as I doubt messing with the interline glue is a good idea (or what?). I wonder if there is an automatic way to accomplish this? **Can I prevent TeX from adjusting the line height based on the size of inline math?**

You might think:

> But what if you want to place large structures, like matrices, in inline math? Certainly you do not want them to collide with the adjacent lines?

But the *fact* is that I *never* place matrices or similar large constructions in inline math. In my opinion, such things belong entirely in displayed math.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Consider the map~$\Ad_{g_0^2}$.
La la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la.
And the algebra~$\widetilde{A}$.
\lipsum[1]

Consider the map~\smash{$\Ad_{g_0^2}$}.
La la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la.
And the algebra~\smash{$\widetilde{A}$}.
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: For small problems with `\tilde{A}`, you can use in the preamble something like `\setstretch{1.06}` from `setspace`. Personally, I consider the interline spacing in LaTeX is *very* tight.

Comment: consider your example.  you lucked out.  it could have happened that the accented A came right under the expression with the subscript.  then you be out of luck -- or you could rewrite.  (la)tex does not know *where* on adjacent lines the potential conflicts appear; it's undoubtedly possible -- with an extensive redesign of the tex internals -- to record and use this information, but given the restrictions under which tex was created, it's quite amazing that it works as well as it does.  nobody has yet improved the math handling, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I am well aware that such collisions might happen. But they will happen independently of whether `\smash`ing is done automatically or manually. In both cases, the solution for me is to rewrite the text. To be clear, I do not, under *any circumstances*, want uneven line spacing. I prefer TeX to let the lines collide instead and then leave it to me to rewrite what I find necessary.

Comment: if you use `\(..\)` for inline math then you just need `\def\(#1\){\smash{$#1$}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Will there be unwanted side effects of doing this globally?

Comment: For instance, egreg discusses some here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116484/19809

Comment: Have you tried increasing \baselineskip?  (Possibly \normalbaselineskip as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting a second answer as I got drawn back to this page by a comment ping and I see that there is only a luatex answer when a simpler classic tex answer is possible.

If you set `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen` then tex will preserve baseline with no limit on the amount of overlapping that would cause.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen

Consider the map~$\Ad_{g_0^2}$.
La la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la.
And the algebra~$\widetilde{A}$.
\lipsum[1]

Consider the map~\smash{$\Ad_{g_0^2}$}.
La la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la.
And the algebra~\smash{$\widetilde{A}$}.
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: And if the high/low elements happen to be right above/below one another, they will be happy to overlap.  (You've said that, though it doesn't stand out.)  Safer might be `\lineskiplimit=0pt`; then adjacent anomalies will merely be set touching, not overlapping.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the OP _wants_ overlapping, preserving the baseline at all costs.

Comment: "the OP wants overlapping" may be true, but some future newbie may be looking for a slightly less drastic solution without realizing it, and be rather surprised when there's a dense blob in the middle of a paragraph.

Comment: well yes but the question is fairly explicit that it asks to stay on the grid, doing that and rewriting the text as needed is not a completely  bad option. It is a shame the MWE from the question didn't have a few more `la` so that the accented A hit the subscript on the line above but so be it

Comment: This solution breaks the spacing inside and around `tikz-cd` diagrams completely, for some reason. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: @Gaussler well presumably not broken but just as specified the lines overlap rather than space themselves off the grid, just put `\lineskiplimit=\normallineskiplimit`  where you want to revert to the normal behaviour.

Comment: This does not work for my case. Could you have a look? Thanks. https://gist.github.com/neruthes/9ace5a955a3d47f084b2b45625f932e4

Comment: @user3332315 look at what? Make an example and post a question if you have a question about alignment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Here is the question, thanks. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652624

Answer (score 3):

Here's a luatex version that could be made more robust but after the linebreaking it uses a callback to set the height and depth of boxes and (s) replace any baselineskip or lineskip glue by a fixed value.  (Probably it should preserve the height of the first box and the depth of the last, left as an exercise..

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}


\directlua{
  function fixlines(h,c)
    local pd=0
    print('code: ' .. type(c) .. ':' .. c)
    for n in node.traverse(h) do
      %
      % smash boxes
      if n.id==0 then
        n.depth=0
        n.height=0
      end
      %
      % lineskip or baselineskip set to 12pt
      if n.id==12 and (n.subtype==1 or n.subtype==2) then
        n.width=786432 % 12pt in sp
      end
    end
    return h
  end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback('post_linebreak_filter', fixlines, 'fix line spacing')
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


Consider the map~$\Ad_{g_0^2}$.
La la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la.
And the algebra~$\widetilde{A}$.
\lipsum[1]

Consider the map~\smash{$\Ad_{g_0^2}$}.
La la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la.
And the algebra~\smash{$\widetilde{A}$}.
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with making more robust? Can you tell me an idea? :)

Comment: @WeißerKater your guess of what was in my head 4 years ago is as good as mine:-) I would think apart from the first and last line issues I mention i was concerned that I am not checking if there is any existing use of this callback, but looking at this I think it is over-complicated and I posted another answer just now.

Comment: I like this answer. It gave me some ideas to get grid typesetting, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581293/using-post-linebreak-filter-in-luatex-to-set-height-and-depth-of-boxes. :)